# Ribbon failed fetching serverlist from Eureka

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

I'm trying to use ribbon together with eureka, but my consumer application failed with error below:

```
2021-01-07 19:02:20.441  INFO 2768 --- [io-10100-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-01-07 19:02:20.441  INFO 2768 --- [io-10100-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-01-07 19:02:20.443  INFO 2768 --- [io-10100-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2021-01-07 19:02:20.672  INFO 2768 --- [io-10100-exec-1] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: greeting.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2021-01-07 19:02:20.719  INFO 2768 --- [io-10100-exec-1] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client: greeting instantiated a LoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=greeting,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
2021-01-07 19:02:20.728  INFO 2768 --- [io-10100-exec-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
2021-01-07 19:02:20.731  INFO 2768 --- [io-10100-exec-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client greeting initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=greeting,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList@14e118c9
2021-01-07 19:02:20.766 ERROR 2768 --- [io-10100-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for greeting] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for greeting
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:119) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:99) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-commons-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:775) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:710) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:333) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at com.example.demo.GreetingService.getGreeting(GreetingService.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.WebController.index(WebController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

My service application is 'greeting', and my consumer app is 'webservice'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivYZu.png)

webservice main application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class WebApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate rest() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder().build();
    }

}
```

code for webservice calling greeting service

```
/**
 * @author Ryan Baxter
 */
@Service
public class GreetingService {
    private static final String URL = "http://greeting";

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate rest;

    public GreetingService(RestTemplate rest) {
        this.rest = rest;
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        return rest.getForObject(URL, String.class);
    }

    public String getGreeting(String locale) {
        return rest.getForObject(new StringBuilder().append(URL).append("/").append(locale).toString(), String.class);
    }
}
```

webservice pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>web</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0-RC1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>ribbon-eureka</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

boostrap.yml of webservice

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  application:
    name: webservice
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      register-with-eureka: true
      fetch-registry: true
      defaultZone: http://username:passwd@eurekaserver:3000/eureka
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
```

application.yml of webservice

```
greeting:
  ribbon:
    eureka:
      enabled: true
#    listOfServers: localhost:9090 
# greeting service runs on 9090, with this line, webservice can work; without this line, the error occurs.
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 15000
```

when I debugged and stepped into my code, I found the ServerList fo LoadBalancer instance is empty
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPngp.png)

If I hardcode the ServerList for greeting in application.yml, it could work. But with eureka, it failed.
Please help me.

Comment: Can you see your `greeting` service UP in Eureka?

Comment: yes, I can see all my services are up in the Eureka panel.

Comment: Could you add your sample to GitHub and post a link?

Comment: Could you modify your resttemplate bean
"@Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate rest(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }"